# Help with SQL aggregate functions

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I've been learning SQL for about a day now and I've run into a road bump. Please help me with the following questions:

```
STUDENT (**StudentNumber**, StudentName, TutorialNumber)
TUTORIAL (**TutorialNumber**, Day, Time, Room, TutorInCharge)
ASSESSMENT (**AssessmentNumber**, AssessmentTitle, MarkOutOf)
MARK (**AssessmentNumber**, **StudentNumber**, RawMark)
```

PK and FK are identified within "**". I need to generate queries that:

1) List of assessment tasks results showing: Assessment Number, Assessment Title, and average Raw Mark. I know how to use the avg function for a single column, but to display something for multiple columns... a little unsure here.

My attempt:

```
SELECT RawMark, AssessmentNumber, AsessmentTitle
FROM MARK, ASSESSMENT
WHERE RawMark = (SELECT (RawMark) FROM MARK)
AND MARK.AssessmentNumber = ASSESSMENT.AssessmentNumber;
```

2) Report on tutorial enrollment showing: Tutorial Number, Day, Room, Tutor in Charge and number of students enrolled. Same as the avg function, now for the count function. Would this require 2 queries?

3) List each student's Raw Mark in each of the assessment tasks showing: Assessment Number, Assessment Title, Student Number, Student Name, Raw Mark, Tutor in Charge and Time. Sort on Tutor in Charge, Day and Time.

Comment: Sounds like homework, is it? You should take a crack at it, if you have then post your progress.

Comment: @SQLrookie - Based on what you have put in the question, you seem to be on the right track! I suggest you post whatever you have got so far and people here will be glad to suggest ways to improve on it, if any

Comment: Okay I'll post up what I have so far.

Comment: another hint: number 2 doesn't require two queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for the first one, just take the logic and see if you can expand it to the other questions. I find that these things can be hard to lear if you can't find any solid examples but once you get the hang of it you'll sort it out pretty quick.

1)

```
SELECT a.AssessmentNumber, a.AssessmentTitle, AVG(RawMark)
FROM ASSESSMENT a LEFT JOIN MARK m ON a.AssessmentNumber = m.AssessmentNumber
GROUP BY a.AssessmentNumber, a.AssessmentTitle
```

OR not using a left join or alias table names

```
SELECT ASSESSMENT.AssessmentNumber, ASSESSMENT.AssessmentTitle, AVG(RawMark)
FROM ASSESSMENT,MARK
WHERE ASSESSMENT.AssessmentNumber = MARK.AssessmentNumber
GROUP BY ASSESSMENT.AssessmentNumber, ASSESSMENT.AssessmentTitle
```

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't been taught the LEFT JOIN... are there any other methods?

Comment: Depending on the structure of the data you could use an INNER JOIN or even just the JOIN key word.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll have a look at the others.